# How do you read/write TUN/TAP interfaces with python3?

Tags: python-3.x

There is code that works great for python 2 here: https://gist.github.com/glacjay/585369, but running that same code on python3 (3.4 and 3.5 tested) the open call fails with:

```
tun = open('/dev/net/tun', 'r+b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.
```

I found suggestions to add buffering=0 to the open call.  The open call succeeded when I did that, but when I tried to read the tap device I got nothing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what did not work for you when using `buffering=0`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a similar code to implement TUN/TAP interfaces support in Scapy, and for what it's worth, using `buffering=0` worked fine in this case.